# How do you add icons to THIS tab nativgator?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

```
const OneNav = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: pages.Home},
  Social: {screen: pages.Social},
  House: {screen: pages.House},
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
});

const TwoNav = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: Two}
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
});

const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {screen: OneNav},
  Interact: {screen: TwoNav},
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Check',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerTitle: () => (
      <View>
        <Logo />
      </View>)
  }
});
```

Right now i have a tab navigator with 2 tabs, Home and Interact. How do I add icons in the navigator for each tab? Please show me how I would do that in the code above, not some example code from the React Native website. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: OneNav,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="home" type="font-awesome" color={tintColor} />,
    }),
  },
  Interact: {
    screen: TwoNav,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="home" type="font-awesome" color={tintColor} />,
    }),
  },
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Check',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerTitle: () => (
      <View>
        <Logo />
      </View>)
  }
});
```